# How to take contents of a tab and insert them inside a node

Tags: nodes, routes, entities

I guess this is a pretty basic Drupal thing, but I'm not experienced with coding. I am using the [Petition node](https://drupal.org/project/petition_node) module which displays a petition form and the results of that petition inside a tab on the same page. I found the code for this on line 174 of the petition.module:

```
$items['node/%petition_menu/signatures'] = array(
'title' => 'Signatures',
'page callback' => 'petition_signature_page',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => 'petition_signature_access',
'access arguments' => array(1),
'weight' => 1,
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
```

I want to render the signatures right next to the petition form, on the petition node page. How can I do this? My guess is that I could use this code and insert it inside the node template, but I need some instructions for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a block using the block module hooks and you can generate the content of the block by using the page callback function in the menu to get the signatures displayed inside the block. You can then configure the block in whichever region you want.

Another option would be to use the page callback function inside the template file (.tpl file) of the petition  node and print the content near to the petition form.